# Consumer always log print UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION while topic exist but no record value

Tags: apache-kafka

we have one topic name ,as the topic don't have much records in , so we our server always show below log

`[Consumer clientId=consumer-elasticsearch_primary_recent_group-15, groupId=elasticsearch_primary_recent_group] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 19238376 : {jp3_meeting_recentcontact_webex_notification=UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION}`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIZbz.png)

how can we avoid this kind of log , and why generate this kind of log

Comment: The error doesn't mean there are no messages. It means the topic doesn't exist at all. Please show the output of `kafka-topics --describe --topic jp3_meeting_recentcontact_webex_notification`. If that also fails, then you have your answer... You "avoid" the log by not subscribing the consumer to that topic...

Comment: ./kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server jp3-kafka-s.webex.com:9092 --describe "jp3_meeting_recentcontact_webex_notification" |grep jp3_meeting_recentcontact_webex_notification
Topic: jp3_meeting_recentcontact_webex_notificationn PartitionCount: 5 ReplicationFactor: 2 Configs: segment.bytes=1073741824,retention.ms=259200000,message.format.version=2.8-IV1,delete.retention.ms=86400000
 Topic: jp3_meeting_recentcontact_webex_notificationn Partition: 0 Leader: 229 Replicas: 229,228 Isr: 228,229
 ....

Comment: you can see that @OneCricketeer, the topic exist it ,but consumer client still report this kind of issue

Comment: Actually, no, that output there has two n's at the end of `notification`. `Topic: jp3_meeting_recentcontact_webex_notificationn`

Comment: I did not capture all data , but I can confirm the topic exist . Any other idea?

Comment: Then [edit] your question to include all the data I asked for. You don't need to show us the configs or partitions, just that that topic does really exist. Or like I said, don't make your consumer subscribe to the topic ; show your consumer code